# convert Ruby to C languge, Would anyone care to take a look?

Tags: c, ruby, popen

I have seen this sample written in Ruby code, how i can simulate it in C language?

```
  Open3.popen3(command) do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
      @stop_stdin = stdin
      while !stdout.eof do 
        output = stdout.read(1024 * 100)
        list_pipes.each do |out|
          out.print output
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280571/how-to-control-popen-stdin-stdout-stderr-redirection) is a good start for learning about `popen`.

Answer (score 2):

The popen man page has an example that should help:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html