# How to make this pipe work in c++?

Tags: c++, pipe

I am  programming a shell in c++. It needs to be able to pipe the output from one thing to another. For example, in linux, you can pipe a textfile to more by doing `cat textfile | more`.

My function to pipe one thing to another is declared like this:

```
void pipeinput(string input, string output);
```

I send "cat textfile" as the input, and "more" as the output.

In c++ examples that show how to make pipes, fopen() is used. What do I send as my input to `fopen()`? I have seen c++ examples of pipeing using `dup2` and without suing `dup2`. What's dup2 used for? How do you know if you need to use it or not?

Comment: You don't know what a pipe is?

Comment: @Phenom We do - you (apparently) don't.

Comment: If you guys are smart then you should be able to understand my question as it is written.

Comment: @Phenom: Being smart does not infer one with psychic powers.

Comment: @Phenom: Please read the FAQ. There's a link at the top of each page.

Comment: Since you can use `more textfile`, this isn't a good example.

Comment: Or even `more <textfile` if "more" is replaced by something that must read stdin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at popen(3), which is a way to avoid execvp.

Comment: One thing to note is that you can easily get stdout but if you also want to stderr, take a look at previous post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280571/how-to-control-popen-stdin-stdout-stderr-redirection In the past, I had to spend some amount of time to figure out when there was an error in the command.

Answer (score 4):

For a simple, two-command pipeline, the function interface you propose may be sufficient.  For the general case of an N-stage pipeline, I don't think it is flexible enough.

The `pipe()` system call is used to create a pipe.  In context, you will be creating one pipe before forking.  One of the two processes will arrange for the write end of the pipe to become its standard output (probably using `dup2()`), and will then close both of the file descriptors originally returned by `pipe()`.  It will then execute the command that writes to the pipe (`cat textfile` in your example).  The other process will arrange for the read enc of the pipe to become its standard input (probably using `dup2()` again), and will then close both of the file descriptor originally returned by `pipe()`.  It will then execute the command that reads from the pipe (`more` in your example).

Of course, there will be still a third process around - the parent shell process - which forked off a child to run the entire pipeline.  You might decide you want to refine the mechanisms a bit if you want to track the statuses of each process in the pipeline; the process organization is then a bit different.

Comment: cat textfile will write to stdout, correct? So what I'm actually pipeing is stdout? What's the code to do that?

Comment: @Phenom: what I said in my answer: _arrange for the write end of the pipe to become its standard output (probably using `dup2()`), and will then close both of the file descriptors originally returned by `pipe()`. It will then execute the command that writes to the pipe (`cat textfile` in your example)_

Comment: Cool. I thought that dup2() was just a safer form of close(). However, it seems that it can do redirection of stdout as well.

Answer (score 1):

`fopen()` is not used to create pipes.  It can be used to open the file descriptor, but it is not necessary to do so.

Pipes are created with the [`pipe(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) call, before forking off the process.  The subprocess has a little bit of file descriptor management to do before `exec`ing the command.  See the example in `pipe`'s documentation.

Comment: `fopen()` may use a file descriptor behind the scenes, but it creates (opens) a file stream, not a file descriptor.

Comment: @Johnathan:  I meant that the `fdopen()` variant of `fopen()` can be used to open an existing file descriptor.