# How to pipe stdout in c++

Tags: c++, pipe, stdout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make this pipe work in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845151/how-to-make-this-pipe-work-in-c)

In Linux, the following command will display the contents of textfile:

```
cat textfile
```

This output can be piped to a command like more like this:

```
cat textfile | more
```

I want to do this programmatically in c++. My program will first execute "cat textfile" by using execvp. Then it needs to capture the output from cat in stdout so that it can pipe this to more. I know how to make a pipe in c++. The problem is capturing stdout. How can this be done?