# How to read the bash standard error in C++?

Tags: c++, error-handling, popen, stderr

Is it possible read the standard error generated by a wrong bash function in C++?
For example if I use the popen function, can I read the standard error with cerr and handle it?

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280571/how-to-control-popen-stdin-stdout-stderr-redirection

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're looking for [`dup`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/dup/) that allows duplicating opened file descriptors (one of them would be `stderr`).