# from python, cancelling C script using "ctr c" signal to command line

Tags: python, c

i call a python script from a C script using a system call (i know this isn't best practice, but for now it does the intended job).

while the C is running at the command line, i can cancel it using Ctrl-C.

when i am running the python script, when the code follows into particular if clauses, i would like to cancel the C script using a Ctr-C call to the command line, the same as if i could do it manually.

is this possible please?

Comment: Wouldn't the python system call be synchronous?

Comment: What is the current behaviour?

Comment: It sound like the C program is waiting for the python program to finish, you need to catch the keyboard interrupt in C and pass it onto the python process, or trigger one in the python process

Comment: This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280571/how-to-control-popen-stdin-stdout-stderr-redirection
You can try to send Ctl-C to command's stdin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import signal
import os

os.kill(0, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
```