# Can I run multiple instances of the Ruby interpreter in the same process?

Tags: c++, c, ruby

I have an application which needs to run Ruby code interfacing with the application itself as a kind of extension. The problem is, I need to be able to run separate instances of the Ruby interpreter because one extension cannot affect the other.

The other issue is that I require the interpreter to be fully included in my executable, so Rubinius is out of question. MRuby, although still in development, seems to be able to run like this, but is too limited. Is there any way to do it with MRI or any other implementation more capable than MRuby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What language are you writing your base application in? C++?

You can fork Ruby tasks, which would have separate Ruby instances running, each would be independent and autonomous. You'd have to decide if how you want to talk to, and control, them. Or you could use some IPC, using `popen` to talk back and forth between your code and the running Ruby apps.

It sounds like you're at the "gee, wouldn't it be nice if" stage, not the "How do I do this?" stage. Look at "[how to control popen stdin, stdout, stderr redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280571/how-to-control-popen-stdin-stdout-stderr-redirection)" for further discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Rubinius, JRuby and IronRuby are the only ones I know off-hand to be capable of having multiple Ruby Environments per process.