# piping stderr to a buffer

Tags: c, windows, gcc, gtk, stderr

In a GThread I have code as such

```
char *commandLine [1024];
sprintf(commandLine, "gcc myfile.c -o myfile.exe 2>&1");

FILE*           pipein_fp;
extern FILE*    popen();
static char     buffer [1024];

pipein_fp = popen(commandLine, "r");
while(fgets(buffer, 1024, pipein_fp) != NULL) g_print("\n%s", buffer);
pclose(pipein_fp);
```

so `2>&1` is supposed to redirect stderr to stdout and the piped g_print is supposed to print out the gcc's stderr output. But it does nothing.
What am I possibly doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure the program has errors? If there are no errors, it won't print anything to stderr.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has an error, Please change

```
char *commandLine [1024];
sprintf(commandLine, "gcc myfile.c -o myfile.exe 2>&1");
```

to

```
char commandLine [1024];
sprintf(commandLine, "gcc myfile.c -o myfile.exe 2>&1");
```

For [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/), the first parameter is `char* str`.

You can read [how to control popen stdin, stdout, stderr redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280571/how-to-control-popen-stdin-stdout-stderr-redirection)

Comment: I didn't copy that part and decided to write it on-hand here. This is how this mistake was born, but it's too late to edit it anyway. I upvoted though I can't submit it as solution, because I am too idiotic and the code I was compiling wasn't bad.