# How do I run, give input and get output from another process using C++

Tags: c++, unix, chess

I'm currently making my own in-terminal Chess GUI and I've made it compatible with the Universal Chess Interface (UCI) for Chess engines. I'd like to connect the GUI to stockfish.exe (chess engine) by passing UCI commands from my program into the chess engine and receiving output from the separate chess engine process.

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: pipes are the usual way to do this

Comment: [popen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45202379/10077) might be one way to accomplish this.

Comment: @FredLarson Right, I failed to notice that. Pipes are still probably the way to go however.

Comment: @john: Yes, and I think `popen` gives you only one of the pipes needed. I think my suggestion is insufficient.

Comment: @FredLarson There is `popen2`

Comment: @john: Is `popen2` standard? I'm not finding much about it.

Comment: @FredLarson I thought it was but it seems not. So I guess you have to do everything by hand, fork, exec, pipe and all that stuff. I shouldn't say any more since I'm not an expert. I'm sure a google search can find plenty of examples.