# Is there any "modern" way to create ChildProcess with redirected stdin and stdout in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, stdout, stdin, child-process

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [this](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/190351/how-to-spawn-console-processes-with-redirected-standard-handles) examples to start a Child process with redirected stdin and stdout, but both of them seem to be really outdated and c-based.(using HANDLE and stuff)

Are there any ways to do that with more c++? (Windows, if possible)

_popen() function is close, but it uses FILE* and only allows stdin OR stdout, not both at the same time.

Comment: `boost::process`, also I must mention that those examples are up to date and any library implementing process spawning is just a wrapper around C API calls and HANDLEs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to control popen stdin, stdout, stderr redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280571/how-to-control-popen-stdin-stdout-stderr-redirection)

Answer (score 0):

Child processes are not defined in the C or C++ standards.

You need to look outside of that to boost, posix or Windows extensions.

Comment: Not entirely true.  `system()` in `stdlib.h` is part of the C and C++ standards.  OTOH child I/O redirections are platform-dependent (self-redirection is standard using `freopen()` in `stdio.h`).

Comment: @BenVoigt it's not part of the specification of `system` that it creates a child process - it "invokes the command processor".  If I'm reading it right, using `system` is actually UB! It's defined by posix to be equivalent to `fork`/`execl sh -c`, but that's posix not C