# How to redirect info like "Aborted (core dumped)" when execute "./a.out"

Tags: c, redirect, stdout, popen, stderr

There is a .out file, which will cause `Aborted (core dumped)` infomation when running.

I want to put this information `Aborted (core dumped)` into a file.

I want to put it into my program actually, but I have redirect problem. Once this problem solved, I can put it in my program by redirect and popen().

I try `./a.out 2>file`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to control popen stdin, stdout, stderr redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280571/how-to-control-popen-stdin-stdout-stderr-redirection)

Comment: Q: How can I get both stderr and stdout for command like ./a.out?  A: `./a.out 2>&1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting standard error for `a.out` won't do anything since `a.out` doesn't actually write the `Aborted (core dumped)` message. This message is written [by the shell itself](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/d233b485e83c3a784b803fb894280773f16f2deb/nojobs.c#L896) in response to an abnormal status returned when it calls [`waitpid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) or similar on your process.

In order to obtain the same information programmatically, you'll need to check the exit code which will be present in `$?`. Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) will result in exit code 128+11=139; SIGABRT (signal 6) should result in exit code 134.